# The column space of block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do we know extra about the column space (or other subspaces) of a block diagonal matrix in general and the kronecker product of the identity matrix with an arbitrary matrix (so block diagonal with repeated blocks along diagonal) in particular?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a block-diagonal matrix
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&A_2&\cdots&0\\
0&\cdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&A_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then when we perform row-reduction the different matrices will not interact. In other words, the row-reduced echelon form of $X$ is (up to some exchanging of rows to put all zero rows at the bottom)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
R_1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&R_2&\cdots&0\\
0&\cdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&R_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $R_j$ is the RREF of $A_j$. So the dimension of the column space of $A$ is the sum of the dimensions of the column spaces of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$.

Comment: So we know about the dimension of the column space but do we know something about the relation between the column space of the block diagonal matrix and the column space of the block matrices?

Comment: I'm  not sure what kind of relation you expect.